# TypeError: f is null when using ASP.NET MVC4 Bundles

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am getting the following error when using bundles in release mode:

> TypeError: f is null

I do not have any issues with my JS code when running in debug mode. But for some reason, I am getting the error once the files are actually bundled. I have defined the following bundles:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/Common/jquery/jquery-{version}.js", 
                    "~/Scripts/Common/jquery/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Common/jquery/jquery.labelify.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/login").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Common/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js",
            "~/Scripts/Common/knockout/json2.js",
           "~/Scripts/Common/knockout/knockout.validation.min.js",
           "~/Scripts/Common/knockout/KnockoutValidationConfiguration.js",
           "~/Scripts/App/Common/LoginViewModel.js"
           ));
```

And I am rendering the bundles inside the header of the page. And at the bottom of my `Login.cshtml` file, I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var context = new LoginViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(context, document.getElementById('login_form'));
    });
</script>
```

When I comment it out, I do not get the error anymore.

I am not sure whether this is caused by the `LoginViewModel` or maybe one of the libraries being used. Anyway, here's the `LoginViewModel` code:

```
function LoginViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Username = ko.observable().extend({ required: { message: "Nom d'utilisateur est obligatoire" } });
    self.Password = ko.observable().extend({ required: { message: 'Mot de passe est obligatoire' } });
    self.ErrorMessage = ko.observable();
    self.enableButton = ko.computed(function () {
        var errors = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.validation.group(self));
        return (errors.length == 0);
    });

    self.onLogin = function () {
        var credentials = ko.toJSON({
            Username: self.Username(),
            Password: self.Password()
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/Login",
            type: "post",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: credentials,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data && data.result == "success") {
                    self.ErrorMessage("");
                    window.location = data.targetUrl;
                }
                else if (data && data.result == "failure") {
                    self.ErrorMessage(data.errorMessage);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Any thoughts? How can I debug that and why is it only happening in release mode?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `"~/Scripts/Common/knockout/knockout.validation.min.js"`, use the development file instead: `"~/Scripts/Common/knockout/knockout.validation.js"`.

Comment: I've just commented out all references to knockout validation and the error was gone. So I'm guessing there's something wrong with this library? I did what you suggested, but it did not solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't answer your question because I don't know knockout.validation. I just know that you can't add a .min file to a bundle.